# How to have the height an element resize to an increment of 32?

Tags: html, css

I have a div in an HTML page that has a repeating grid background. I want to be able to put stuff like text and images into the div, but have it resize on an increment of 32 pixels, so that the grid doesn't get cut off. I know it's possible to do this with JavaScript, but is it possible to do this with only CSS?

Comment: Not  possible with CSS dynamically but CSS-Grid does give you options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know beforehand how much space you need to take, using `calc` could be an option. Now if you don't know and want to calculate that dynamically, there you will need js or sass/less variables.
Example:

```css
.container{
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.first-item{
  width: calc(32px);
  height: calc(32px);
  background-color: red;
}

.second-item{
  width: calc(32px * 2);
  height: calc(32px * 2);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.third-item{
  width: calc(32px * 10);
  height: calc(32px * 10);
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-item"></div>
  <div class="second-item"></div>
  <div class="third-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured out how to do it with simple JavaScript, this is a good solution though.